# How to store a graph of sql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, graph

Lets say we have quite a few tables (T1, T2... T50), and we would like to have n to n relations between all of them.

What would be a propper way of implementig that.
Having a relations table for each pair of Tx and Ty would not be practical if the number of tables goes up to 100 or more.

The current solution I have is

```
relationships_table
id_x, table_name_x, id_y, table_name_y
```

for storing all the relationships. This way adding new tables is trivial, but what are the disadvantages?

**1)** What is a better way of supporting such a use case, if we're limited to sql?

**2)** How to efficiently solve this if we're not limited to sql?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide  a concrete example.  There is no issue in having multiple junction tables . . . I doubt you would need 100*99/2 for all pairs of tables, but without a real example it is hard to figure out the logic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the issue is that we will probably need to add new tables, and the extra work with having multiple junction tables would cause a lot of owerhead, and getting all neighbours for one object would be a very complicated query. For teh usecase, look at this https://github.com/reciprocity/ggrc-core. I tried to simlify the problem as much as possible for now. but we have 50+ different objects that have mappings between them.

Comment: . . Storing different objects in different tables may not be the right solution.  A generic relationships table could work for storing the data, but it would not guarantee referential integrity, allow foreign key constraints, or permit efficient use of indexes.  I suspect that your data model could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you proposed is the most reasonable solution to the stated problem. But the problem seems somewhat unreasonable.

If you need a graph, then you only need two tables, one for the nodes and another one for the edges.

If some nodes are of specific types then you can have extra specialization tables for them.

Answer (score 0):

Add only the essential Relation tables.  tblA relates to tblB, and tblB relates to tblC.  So, *usually* that implies that you can get from A to C via

```
FROM tblA
JOIN tblB ON ...
JOIN tblC ON ...
```

Won't this do?  And need not much more than 50 extra tables?  And be a lot cleaner?

Comment: What if we want to support a fully connected graph. That is what's giving me problems.

Comment: Everything is _directly_ connected to everything else?  2500 connections?  What are you modeling?  Maybe a database is not the right place for the connections.  The database could still be the repository for information about the entities.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem and I had a sligthly different approach. I added a table called relationable, only storing an id and all tables appearing in the graph have a reference to this table. I make sure on my own that only one element references an relationable entry in the whole database (This is actually what boters me the most, but in practice it is not such a problem just not looking nice). and then a relation table for the n to n relationship between relationable.

To make my point I add an example i MADE IN MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE relationable
(
  relationable_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

in the relation table I added a name, because my vertices have a name, there might even be multiple vertices between two nodes with different names.

```
CREATE TABLE relation
(
 from_id INT NOT NULL,
 to_id INT NOT NULL,
 name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (from_id) REFERENCES relationable(relationable_id) ON DELETE     CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY (to_id)   REFERENCES relationable(relationable_id) ON DELETE     CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

finally a table which appears in the graph would look like the following

```
  CREATE TABLE place
 (
   place_id INT NOT NULL,
   name VARCAHR(255),
   FOREIGN KEY (PLACE_ID) REFERENCES relationable(relationable_id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Now obviously this has pros and cons,

### cons

- You need to make sure yourself that a relationable is only referenced once. Inside one table this is taken care of by PRIMARY KEY but over all tables this is not done.
- You might need a huge int for the id of relationable.
- The table relation might get quite big.

### pros

- To errase an entry and all its relations deleting the relationable entry suffices, all entrys in relation and the respective table will be deleted.
- When joining two tables there is no need for the relationable table.